# I want to iterate over a List<T> in C#, not sure how

Tags: c#

How can I iterate over a `List<T>` in C#? I've disabled the class properties in both of the `foreach` loops in the sandbox example below.

I also get an error in the `foreach` line if I try to use the right type in place of var.

Does the `List<T>` need to be cast as a specific kind of list? Regardless of the function app timeout setting, 230 seconds is the maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to respond to a request. This is because of the default idle timeout of Azure Load Balancer.

```
void Main() 
{
    var listOfCars = new Car().GetCars();
    var listOfCartoons = new Cartoon().GetCartoons();

    ShowLists(listOfCars);
    ShowLists(listOfCartoons);
}

public static void ShowLists<T>(List<T> list) 
{
    Type t = list.GetType();

    if (t == typeof(List<Car>)) 
    {
        foreach (var c in list) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        foreach (Cartoon c in list) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.);
        }
    }
}

public class Car 
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public List<Car> GetCars() 
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>();
        cars.Add(new Car() { Manufacturer = "VW", Model = "Phaeton", Country = "Germany" });
        cars.Add(new Car() { Manufacturer = "Land Rover", Model = "Range Rover Sport", Country = "UK" });
        return cars;
    }
}

public class Cartoon 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Cartoon> GetCartoons() 
    {
        var cartoons = new List<Cartoon>();
        cartoons.Add(new Cartoon() { Title = "Family Guy" });
        cartoons.Add(new Cartoon() { Title = "Americaan Dad" });
        return cartoons;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Iterating through the list of cars or cartoons then printing the items to the console? Or is the console writing is just a placeholder in the question for actual business logic?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense as it is. The whole point of using generics is to be able to do the same thing to an object within a method no matter the type. If you are checking the type in the method and doing something different for different types then you totally defeat the purpose of a generic method and shouldn't be using one. In your case, you should simply write two overloads for the two different types. If you want to learn about generics, use a different example because yours is just wrong as it is.

Comment: BTW, your `GetCars` and `GetCartoons` methods should be static. It doesn't make sense to create an instance whose sole purpose is to create a list of other instances.

Comment: `foreach (Car c in list.Cast<Car>())`. Code might do what you want then but seems still not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectDumper.NET/4.1.3?_src=template)  for this. Below are two different styles for displaying your data (I guess its juz for reference I mean your content in code).

```html
namespace DumpingApp;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Dump";
        var listOfCars = new Car().GetCars();
        var listOfCartoons = new Cartoon().GetCartoons();

        Console.WriteLine(ObjectDumper.Dump(listOfCars));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(ObjectDumper.Dump(listOfCartoons, DumpStyle.CSharp));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Car
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public List<Car> GetCars()
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>();
        cars.Add(new Car() { Manufacturer = "VW", Model = "Phaeton", Country = "Germany" });
        cars.Add(new Car() { Manufacturer = "Land Rover", Model = "Range Rover Sport", Country = "UK" });
        return cars;
    }
}

public class Cartoon
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Cartoon> GetCartoons()
    {
        var cartoons = new List<Cartoon>();
        cartoons.Add(new Cartoon() { Title = "Family Guy" });
        cartoons.Add(new Cartoon() { Title = "Americaan Dad" });
        return cartoons;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears as though you are trying to learn something about using generics but the way you're trying to do so is completely flawed so you'll learn nothing. As I said in the comments, the whole point of generics is to do the same thing for every type so, if you're distinguishing between types and doing something different for each one, you're doing it wrong. In your case, you should simply overload that method:

```cs
public static void ShowList(List<Car> list) 
{
    foreach (var c in list) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Model);
    }
}

public static void ShowList(List<Cartoon> list) 
{
    foreach (Cartoon c in list) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Title);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how you might correctly use a generic method:

```cs
void Main() 
{
    var cars = Car.GetCars();
    var cartoons = Cartoon.GetCartoons();

    ShowList(cars);
    ShowList(cartoons);
}

public static void ShowList<T>(List<T> list) 
{
    foreach (var c in list) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    }
}

public class Car 
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public static List<Car> GetCars() 
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>();
        cars.Add(new Car() { Manufacturer = "VW", Model = "Phaeton", Country = "Germany" });
        cars.Add(new Car() { Manufacturer = "Land Rover", Model = "Range Rover Sport", Country = "UK" });
        return cars;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Manufacturer} {Model} ({Country})";
    }
}

public class Cartoon 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public static List<Cartoon> GetCartoons() 
    {
        var cartoons = new List<Cartoon>();
        cartoons.Add(new Cartoon() { Title = "Family Guy" });
        cartoons.Add(new Cartoon() { Title = "Americaan Dad" });
        return cartoons;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

In this case, the same thing is being done in the generic method regardless of the generic type and any difference in implementation is handled by the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you have a generic method, objects of the generic type can only reference properties that are on the most base type or any interfaces the generic type is constrained to.  Without any constraints, that is effectively `object`, i.e. the base type of all types.  Thus, something like

```
foreach (Cartoon c in list) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.);
}
```

is going to fail because you're asking the compiler to implicitly convert your generic type (which it only knows has to be or inherit from `object`) to a `Cartoon`.  This kind of implicit conversion can't exist because you can't have a custom implicit conversion from a base type to a derived type.

Others have pointed out that you can split this method into two non-generic methods, but if possible, another thing you can do is constrain your generic type using an interface, e.g.

```
public interface ITvShow{
    string Title {get;}
}

public Foo<T>(List<T> input) where T : ITvShow
```

Which will let you define the TV show's Title property as a member of the interface and reference it without any casts on the generic object, since now the generic object is known to implement `ITvShow`.  However, in a case like yours where you can't or don't want to add a common interface to the types, there can be valid use cases to have a generic method that does different things depending on the type of the generic.  To do that, you need to cast either the list or the objects in it to the type you want to deal with in the method.  The nicest way to do this is with a `switch`.

```
public static void ShowList<T>(List<T> list) 
{
    switch(list){
        case List<Cartoon> cartoons:
            foreach (var cartoon in cartoons) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cartoon.ToString());
            }
            break;
        case List<Car> cars:
            foreach (var car in cars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(car.ToString());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```